Cannot import Apollo TestMocks to unit test target in cocoapod library using embedded target
I am trying to use ApolloTestSupport in unit tests. I want to add generated test models to only unit test target. Generated models doesn’t have @testable import MyApp. so cannot use TestMocks.
graphql codegen apollo-codegen-config.json  output segment looks like below.
"output": {
    "testMocks": { "absolute": {
      "path": "../../Tests/GeneratedAPI/Mocks"
    } 
   },
    "schemaTypes": {
      "path": "./GeneratedAPI",
      "moduleType": { "embeddedInTarget": { "name": "MyApp" } }
    },
    "operations": {
      "inSchemaModule": {}
    }

We have requirement not to expose grqphql model outside the cocoapod library. I would like to know how to add graphql generated test mocks to unit target and keep generated actual model embedded to source target.
